# cloud functions emulator cannot read or write to firestore database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I was running my cloud functions locally with the emulator no problems yesterday. When I came back and set my `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=`after a reboot I now cannot read or write to the database. I've deleted my key, created a new one and I still run into the same problem. I've created a simple function that runs with no errors yet it doesn't read or write to the database when ran in the emulator. The `.get()` function says it couldn't find anything and the `.set()` doesn't return anything nor does it write to the DB.

Edit* my functions do run when deployed to firebase, but I have one that parses and loads huge amounts of data that times out that I have to run locally because of how long it takes.

```
exports.dumbFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("test")
    .doc("hello")
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("You got me" + doc.data());
      } else {
        console.log("I couldn't find anything");
      }
    });
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("test")
    .doc("test123")
    .set({
      setme: "ok",
      asdf: "asdf"
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("did I error?");
      console.log(err);
    });
  console.log("hi again");

});
```

I've followed the instructions of the following.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

when I run the node.js example in the third link I get the following error messages which I think is my issue but I have no idea why or how to fix this.

```
Unknown network resource requested!
   - URL: "http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance"
  ERROR: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
     at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (/home/ben/Development/polity/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:168:23)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at fulfilled (/home/ben/Development/polity/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:19:58)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

when I `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` it shows that it's set to my JSON file containing my key.

The `Unknown network resource requested!` is something I see on my other functions as well now which is something I didn't receive when they were working.

Any idea?

Much thanks

Comment: You're sending the response to the client before the promises returned by the admin SDK are fully resolved.  Simply calling then and catch do not make your code wait for the result.  As such, I would expect this function to simply not work in many circumstances.

Comment: I've taken `response.sendStatus(200);` out of my example, I forgot to remove it. Even without sending a response it still doesn't work. That function is just an example of a larger issue that happens with all my functions locally ran now.

Comment: Look over your firestore rules. The emulator will silently swallow those errors up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can't get this working but I found a workaround. Using the functions framework for nodejs works just fine.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs